# AngularJS 1.6.1, TypeScript, UI Bootstrap Modal: Why are my global variables stored in session storage being updated by the modal?

Tags: angularjs, typescript, angular-ui-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal, ng-storage

Please help a newb out. I'm using `ngStorage` to store some global variables:

```
//Global Controller
saveGlobalSettings = () => {
        this.$sessionStorage.QuoteTimes = this.quoteTimes;
        this.$sessionStorage.QuoteTypes = this.quoteTypes;
    };
```

I'm using another method in another controller to create objects that use some of the global variables as properties:

```
// Create Controller 
addChannel = (channel) => {            
        channel.QuotingChannelType = channel.QuotingChannelId;             
        console.log(this.$sessionStorage.QuoteTimes);
        channel.QuoteTypes = this.$sessionStorage.QuoteTypes;
        channel.QuoteTimes = this.$sessionStorage.QuoteTimes;
        if (!this.myChannels) { this.myChannels = []; }
        this.myChannels.push(channel);           
    };
```

I'm then using `ng-repeat` to display the objects in `myChannels` in the browser. When clicked, I'm passing the object to an `openDialog()` method:

```
 openPreferencesDialog = (channel) => {
        var options: ng.ui.bootstrap.IModalSettings = {
            templateUrl: 'app/form/templates/editChannelPreferences.html',
            controller: 'EditDialogController',
            controllerAs: '$ctrl',
            resolve: {
                channel: () => channel
            }
        };            
        this.$uibModal.open(options).result
            .then(updatedChannel => console.log(updatedChannel));               
    };
```

The dialog opens as expected, but when I make changes, it is updating the `QuoteTimes` and `QuoteTypes` arrays in `$sessionStorage` (seen from the `console.log` in `addChannel`). So each new object created has the `QuoteTimes` and `QuoteTypes` of the last object I edited. I am completely stumped. My best guess is it's some kind of scope chain problem? Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

UPDATE: I was able to get it working as expected by using `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj));` as follows:

```
openPreferencesDialog = (obj, index) => {           
        var channel = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj));
        var options: ng.ui.bootstrap.IModalSettings = {
            templateUrl: 'app/form/templates/editChannelPreferences.html',
            controller: 'EditDialogController',
            controllerAs: '$ctrl',
            resolve: {
                channel: () => channel
            }
        };            
        this.$uibModal.open(options).result
            .then(updatedChannel =>
            {
                console.log(updatedChannel);
                this.$sessionStorage.myChannels[index].QuoteTimes = updatedChannel.QuoteTimes;
                this.$sessionStorage.myChannels[index].QuoteTypes = updatedChannel.QuoteTypes;
                console.log(this.$sessionStorage.myChannels)
            });               
    };
```

Can anyone explain why this works?

Answer (score 1):

If quote... members of channel object are not primitive type it's normal behaviour. Because they are reference type that both last edited channel object and $sessionstorage have same references to them in memory.